# Setting up public IP address on CentOS 7

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, centos7

When configuring a LAMP server on CentOS 7, do I need to to setup first a public IP address before my website to be accessible on the browser?

I already tried configuring the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and adding the following items:

IPADDR, NETMASK, GATEWAY, DNS1, DNS2

But I'm not sure if I added the right IPADDR, NETMASK, GATEWAY, DNS1 and DNS2, because when I tried to access my IP to the browser it doesn't show the apache page that I already installed. I also already allowed it to the firewall by typing

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I'm not sure if I configured properly the ifcfg-eth0 because when I try to connect to the public ip on my local machine it won't establish a connection

Comment: What happened instead?

Comment: Unable to Connect on browser

Comment: @MichaelHampton I got it now I was able to access it now on my local machine, but I tried it on my phone browser and I can't access it, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is your server directly connected to the internet? is it behind a router? If yes, is the traffic routed, or is NAT used?

Comment: Yes the server is directly connected to the internet and NAT is used. I cannot even access the apache page after installing httpd @GeraldSchneider

Comment: If NAT is used it is NOT connected directly to the internet. In that case you need to configure port forwarding on your router to be able to access it from the internet. Configuring the external IP on the server will not work.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider But will I be able to access it from different devices? Or expose it publicly on the internet?